# multivariate normal computation in matlab

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab, matrix-decomposition

I have a 6 dimensional normal distribution with mean zero and co-variance matrix given as follows:

$S_{ij} = 1 for i==j$

$S_{1j} = sqrt(0.5) for j=2,3,4,5,6$

$S_{i1} = sqrt(0.5) for i=2,3,4,5,6$

$S_{ij} = 0.5 for i\neq j, i \neq 1 or j \neq 1 $

i.e. the diagonals are all 1. the first row and the first cols is sqrt(0.5) and the rest of the entries are 0.5

Now I have the following code.

```
n=6;
mu = zeros(1,n);
X = ones(1,n);
X=X*0.;
Y = mvncdf(X,mu,S);
```

Y gives me the cumulative prob for the point (0,0,0,0,0,0). I get Y=0.164.

Now I can also compute the probability by transforming the co-variance matrix

```
Sinv = inv(S);
cholS = chol(Sinv,'lower');
cholSinv = inv(cholS);
Z = cholSinv*X';
phi = normcdf(Z,0,1);
Yhat=prod(phi);
```

I get Yhat = 0.0156.

What I am trying to do theoretically is as follows:
For the multivariate case I have

$ \int_{-\infty}^{A} exp(-0.5 * Y'\Sigma Y) dY$   (I am ignoring the normalization)

I have decomposed $\Sigma = C C'$   and also transformed $Y = CZ$

This makes the above integral

$ \int_{-\infty}^{A} exp(-0.5 * Y'\Sigma Y) dY = \int_{-\infty}^{C^{-1} A} exp(-0.5 * Z' Z) dZ$

The integral on the left is computed using my first code snippet.

The integral on the right is separable and can be computed using my second code snippet.

I guess I am making some mistake but I am unable to figure out what. It would be very kind if someone can point out the mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to transform the region you integrate over for the cdf. In terms of $Z$, it's no longer $Z_i<0$. It's $\sum_j C_{ij}Z_j <0$

Comment: did not understand your comment. Can you please clarify.

Comment: You are trying to compute $P(X<0)$ by taking $P(Z<0).$ $Z<0$ is not the same set as $X<0$. The region gets rotated (/stretched) by $C.$ notice your method would imply $P(X<0)$ is the same for any covariance matrix (you can see it hitting a bunch of zeroes and being erased in your code)

Comment: You are probably being thrown off by the fact that $X=0$ is the same point as $Z=0$. It doesn't follow that $X<0$ is the same as $Z<0$. As I said, one's the image of the other under the transformation.

Comment: I still do not see it. You see $\int_{-\infty}^A = \int_{-\infty}^{a_1}...\int_{-\infty}^{a_6}$.  The transformation $C^{-1}A$ changes the limits as $\int_{-\infty}^{ca_1}...\int_{-\infty}^{ca_6}$. I agree the region $<0 $ in the Y-space is getting deformed but so it the integrand and the limits.

Comment: That is not how the limits change. C is not a diagonal matrix. Do the exercise on the bivariate normal case. Do see my point about how you are implying it's always the same thing regardless of covariance? That  shouldn't be the case. For two variables it should be 1/4 for correlation zero and 1/2 for correlation 1.

Comment: ("It" being $P(X_1,X_2 < 0)$) And btw as a hint $.0156 = 1/2^6$... you can see how getting that was inevitable.

Comment: Yes I intuitively agree with you on the issue that you point out $.0156=1/26.0156=1/2^6$.  But I am unable to see the flaw in the analytical formula I have written down. The computation is following the analytics.

Comment: Your analytics have an error... the region of $Z$-space is wrong. I wrote out a full answer that shows how to do the calculation correctly for the case of two variables.

Comment: What if mean is non-zero? Then the later involves the correlation parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see where you're going wrong consider the simpler example of a bivariate normal $(X,Y)$ with covariance matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix}1 & \rho\\\rho & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ for some correlation $-1\le \rho \le 1.$ By Cholesky or otherwise we can represent $X$ and $Y$ as $$ X = Z_1 \\ Y = \rho Z_1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_2 $$ where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent standard normals.

Intuitively we can see that $P(X \le 0,Y \le 0)$ (i.e. the joint CDF evaluated at the zero vector) is $1/4$ for $\rho=0,$ $1/2$ for $\rho=1,$ and $0$ for $\rho = -1.$ So we expect this probability to interpolate between $0$ and $1/2$ as $\rho$ goes between $-1$ and $1.$

However, your second method would say to compute this as $$ P(X\le 0,Y\le 0) = P(Z_1 \le 0, Z_2 \le 0) =P(Z_1\le0)P(Z_2\le 0) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4} $$ which has to be wrong since it doesn't appear to depend on the correlation.

As I mentioned in the comments, your error is that you are taking the probability of the wrong region of $Z$-space. If $X\le 0$ and $Y\le 0,$ then we have $$ Z_1 \le 0 \\ \rho Z_1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_2 \le 0.$$ So we don't want $P(Z_1\le 0, Z_2\le 0).$ What we want is  $$ P(X\le 0,Y\le 0) = P\left(Z_1\le 0, Z_2 \le -\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} Z_1\right).$$

To compute this we need to integrate the density of $Z$ over the appropriate region. If we denote $\phi(x)$ the std normal PDF and $\Phi(x)$ the std normal CDF, we get $$ P(X\le 0, Y\le 0) = \int_{-\infty}^0 \phi(z_1)dz_1\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{\rho z_1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}}\phi(z_2) dz_2 = \int_{-\infty}^0 \phi(z_1)\Phi\left(-\frac{\rho z_1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right)dz_1 \\= \int_0^\infty \phi(z) \Phi\left(\frac{\rho z}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right)dz.$$

This integral can be done exactly, but I can't figure out how and don't want to distract from the point. So let's just see what it gets for a positive correlation $\rho = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2},$ cherry picked to have the integral be easy. Then the quantity reduces to $$ P(X\le 0, Y\le 0) \int_0^\infty \Phi(x)\phi(x)dx = \int_0^\infty \Phi(x)\Phi'(x)dx = \int_{1/2}^1 \Phi d\Phi = \frac{3}{8}.$$ A value between $1/4$ and $1/2$ just like we'd expect.

**Side note:**
Using some combination of Mathematica and trial and error, I get the expression $$ P(X\le 0, Y\le 0) = \frac{1}{2}H(\rho) - \frac{1}{2\pi}\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right)$$ where $H(x)$ is the step function. But this is somewhat beside the point cause your full $6$-variable question probably won't have a nice analytic answer, but you can do it by numerical integration. (But to that point, why not just stick with the built in multivariate normal cumulative someone was nice enough to implement for you.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I understand the issue better now.